# Design and generic List clean up

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have the observer design pattern and Attaching/Detaching the required observers are done via the static methods. I used static method delibrately, since having list of observers for each node could cost a lot in term of memory. Please let me know if I am wrong from design point of view (Is using static methods and variable correct?).

```
    public static void Attach(FormComponentObserverBase observer)
    {
        observers.Add(observer);
    }

    public static void Detach(FormComponentObserverBase observer)
    {
        observers.Remove(observer);
    }

    public static void DetachAll()
    {
        if (observers == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var o in observers)
        {
            Detach(o);
        }
    }

    public static void Notify(MyObservedObject c)
    {
        if (observers == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var o in observers)
        {
            o.Update(c);
        }
}
```

The observers are observing a tree object structure. Since the tree is expensive in term of memory, I want to make sure that I don't keep anything extra in memory. I try to implement the IDisposable interface and via the Dispose method, I want to clean up the observers and other unnecessary instance related objects. In term of observers generic list, will the following be enough to make the list of observers eligible for garbage collection?

```
DetachAll();
observers = null;
```

Comment: Where is the _gain_ to have static methods here? They kill testability and moreover you'll share observers between all instances of your class (so they'll get notifications for objects they didn't register for). Is it correct you Disposte STATIC (then SHARED) objects inside an instance method? Is it what you want? Just drop static and live happy...

Comment: We can't determine what datatype observers is, or what else is in the class? We only see the static methods. "I have the observer design pattern" doesn't really tell us much.

Comment: The thing is if I keep the observers as instance variable, I could end up a lot of copies of the observers for tree nodes. Using static, I am trying to avoid so many copies of observers list. Dispose method will only be called on the root tree node. Is it right approach?

Comment: @mmo: EACH instance has ITS OWN list. What if instance A has observers 1, 2 and 3 and instance B has observers 2, 4 and 5? There is no practical reason to keep a shared list because for each observer you need to keep track of which instances is observing too...

Comment: Last note: first write it simple and straight then "optimize" **if** and **where** needed (after profiling). If the object collection is small then the observer list is insignificant compared to its size even if you have 1000 instances with 30 observers each one...

Comment: @Adriano: Thanks for the input. I want to make sure that everything in the tree is observed by the defined same set of observers. They cannot have different observers. Yes, the number of observers would be few and less than 10. But the tree will be large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Remove` actually removes the observer from the list, then there's nothing else you need to do as far as this data structure is concerned. There's no particular reason to set `observers = null`. That just frees up the small amount of memory used for the list of observers, and it complicates your code because you have to check for `null` everywhere. For example, if your `DetachAll` sets `observers = null`, then your `Attach` has to be:

```
if (observers == null)
{
    // create observers list
}
observers.Add(observer);
```

I wouldn't recommend calling `Dispose` on the observer in the `Detach` method, because the observer might still be an active object.

You probably don't want this to be static. You're better off, from a flexibility and testability standpoint, to use an instance object. If you really need to ensure that your program can't create multiple instances of it, you can implement a singleton design pattern, but that probably won't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the singleton suggestion. It is useful to note.